# How can I split a text file into multiple text files using Perl?

Tags: text-processing, scripting, perl

I have a file ABC_TabDelim.txt that contains the following:

```
00:00:00:00 00:00:05:00 01SC_001.jpg
00:00:14:29 00:00:19:29 01SC_002.jpg
00:01:07:20 00:01:12:20 01SC_003.jpg
00:00:00:00 00:00:03:25 02MI_001.jpg
00:00:03:25 00:00:08:25 02MI_002.jpg
00:00:35:27 00:00:40:27 02MI_003.jpg
00:00:00:00 00:00:05:00 03Bi_001.jpg
00:00:05:19 00:00:10:19 03Bi_002.jpg
00:01:11:17 00:01:16:17 03Bi_003.jpg
00:00:00:00 00:00:05:00 04CG_001.jpg
00:00:11:03 00:00:16:03 04CG_002.jpg
00:01:12:25 00:01:17:25 04CG_003.jpg
```

I would like to split this into multiple files for each instance of 00:00:00:00, outputting it as ABC01_TabDelim.txt, ABC02_TabDelim.txt, ABC03_TabDelim.txt, etc.

So 00:00:00:00 would indicate a new file should begin. Is there any way I can accomplish this with a Perl script?

Answer (score 3):

This will work for the given format. This assumes the file will always start with 00:00:00:00.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $infh, '<', 'ABC_TabDelim.txt') or die $!;

my $outfh;
my $filecount = 0;
while ( my $line = <$infh> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /^00:00:00:00/ ) {
        close($outfh) if $outfh;
        open($outfh, '>', sprintf('ABC%02d_TabDelim.txt', ++$filecount)) or die $!;        
    }
    print {$outfh} $line or die "Failed to write to file: $!";
}

close($outfh);
close($infh);
```

Comment: Don't use a regexp if you don't have to, use `if (substr($line, 0, 11) eq "00:00:00:00")`.

Comment: @goldilocks: what? The regex expresses the intent just fine and avoids having to count the chars (and forgetting to update something if the pattern ever changes).

Comment: @Mat Too bad we lack a `string.startswith()` method that solves that problem :).

Comment: @Mat: the method here is a very minor difference WRT to the maintenance ("forgetting to update...") of hardcoded values (but point taken).  It's not a big deal, just I would consider it poor programming because a regexp is less efficient, resource wise, and using them for everything is kinda over-the-top lazy.  No offence ;)  Also, using substr() is a more specific statement about what you are doing (exact match).

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. No error checking, run as, e.g., `perl split file-to-munge`

**Update:** Script cleanup as suggested by goldilocks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$n = 1;
while(<>) {
    if(/^00:00:00:00/) {
        close($out) if(n != 1);
        $fn = sprintf("ABC%02d_TabDelim.txt", $n++);
        open($out, ">", "$fn");
    }
    print OUT;
}
```

Comment: -1 for use of FILE glob and 2 arg open!  Sorry.

Comment: @goldilocks, that is quite idiomatic Perl 5...

Comment: It's actually idiomatic of Perl <5.6 (c.2000), when it was the only choice (see here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-open-a-file-with-a-leading-%22%3E%22-or-trailing-blanks%3F) There are lots of explanations around for why this is a bad habit, (eg: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=76775519), not the least of which is those bareword typeglob handles are by default in the global namespace regardless of where you declare them. https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/bareword_uppercase_filehandles

Comment: @goldilocks, and that is relevant for a throwaway script because...?

Comment: I am not downvoting but demonstrating bad practices to a new user is not a good thing. For your own throwaway, it's fine.

Comment: @vonbrand it's relevant because of jordanm's point, 1st, and 2nd because there's no good reason to do something the "wrong" way there, throwaway or no.  The 2-arg option and declarable typeglobs persist for backward compatibility with a feature now recognized as something that should never have been.  I did not like being told this either, lol, but it is hard to fight the logic: if you are used to doing it one way, you will tend to do it that way, so you might as well practice the right way to start with, since (once you are used to it), it is not any harder...making the other one *obsolete*.

Comment: PS. If you change it :) I will reverse my vote.

Answer (score 2):

If the output for that sample input is expected to be 4 files, each with 3 lines, each 1st line being one starting with “00:00:00:00” and the other 2 lines the following ones, this will do it:

```
perl -ne 'if(/^[0:]{11}/){close F if$f;open F,sprintf(">ABC%02d_TabDelim.txt",++$f)}print F' ABC_TabDelim.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Perl for that: you can use the standard shell utility [csplit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/csplit.html). There's one limitation: the name of the output files has to be xxx00, xxx01, etc., so you'll need to add the desired suffix afterwards.

```
csplit -s -f ABC ABC_TabDelim.txt '/^00:00:00:00/' '{999999999}'
rm ABC00  # empty file (containing everything up to the first 00:00:00:00)
for x in ABC[0-9][0-9]; do mv "$x" "${x}_TabDelim.txt"; done
```

The `{*}` argument to repeat the previous delimiter as many times as possible is a GNU extension. [POSIX csplit requires a first pass with grep.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46325/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-into-multiple-text-files/46330#46330)

Answer (score 1):

You have a solution for perl, here's one way you could do it with awk:

```
awk '/00:00:00:00/ { out = sprintf("ABC%02d_TabDelimit.txt", ++i) } { print > out }' ABC_TabDelim.txt
```

If you have to split into *many* files you would want to close each file as you go along, prepend the sprintf function with `if(out) close(out)`:

```
awk '/00:00:00:00/ { if(out) close(out); out = sprintf("ABC%02d_TabDelimit.txt", ++i) } { print > out }' ABC_TabDelim.txt
```