# copy sections of a big file into many output files

Tags: text-processing, scripting, text

I have one large file that looks like:

```
Header1

Subheader1

l1 

l1'

l1''

Header2

Subheader2

l2 

l2'

l2''

Headern

Subheader n

ln

ln'

ln''
```

(in which n is ~25K)

I need to paste `l1-l1'', l2-l2'' ... ln-ln''` into different files - say `file1, file2, ... file n` (at a certain line number within the files).

Comment: Des this similar question help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46325/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-into-multiple-text-files

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the relation between Headers and lines. But if the relation is a constant number of lines, you can retrieve the lines numbers with grep then use sed to extract the lines.

For example, to get all lines after Subheader :

```
#!/bin/bash 

file_in=/tmp/test.txt
file_out=/tmp/file1.txt
LINES=`grep -n Subheader $file_in | cut -f1 -d:`
for line in $LINES; do
  echo $line
  line1=$(($line+1))
  sed -n ${line1}p $file_in >> $file_out
done
```

Edit : you can run the script above into a loop :

```
#!/bin/bash

n_max=100
file_in=/tmp/test.txt
file_out=/tmp/file

LINES=`grep -n Subheader $file_in | cut -f1 -d:`
for n in `seq 1 $n_max`; do
  echo "line $n"
  for line in $LINES; do
    line_n=$(($line+$n))
    sed -n ${line_n}p $file_in >> $file_out$n.txt
  done
done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this as follows:

```
perl -Mautodie -lne '
   if ( /Subheader/ ... /Header/ ) {
      open FILE, q[>>], q[file] . ++$a if /Subheader/;
      close FILE if /Header/;
      print FILE if !/Subheader/ && !/Header/;
   }
' large_file.log
```

This will create the mini-files file1, file2, etc.

Perl opens a new filehandle when it encounters a Subheader line.
And it close that filehandle when it encounters the Header line.
for all other lines, it prints to the filehandle.